# Implementation of Thread Pools

Tags: multithreading, pool

I was wondering if anyone knows some good resources for researching how Thread Pools have been implemented. I've been asked to define an algorithm that dynamically adjusts the max thread-pool size. Most resources define the circumstances you would want a thread pool, ie tasks are short lived, but in this problem the circumstances are more varied. Longer tasks as well as short, some cpu intensive, some idling often.

My first answer was "you probably shouldn't be using a thread pool" but I think I should have a real answer.

One thought I had was to have a heuristic to watch the system resources (CPU, memory) and adjust the size accordingly. Or I could monitor threads to see how long they are taking and how int

Comment: The [Smart Thread Pool](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7933/Smart-Thread-Pool) project on codeproject is fairly complicated, but (IIRC) it has all the features you're talking about.

Comment: You should add a .NET tag.  Unmanaged threads are so cheap that this layer of stuff is largely redundant. If unmanaged, just throw 256 threads at the work queue, just in case a large number get blocked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class *SelfTuningExecutors* of the library [therore-concurrent](http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C-2099403956). I had the same need and I decided to implement an extension of the JDK *ThreadPoolExecutor* that could adapt to diverse types of tasks. You may want to check out this page [link](http://therore.net/getting-the-maximum-performance-of-your-java-processes/)